# OpenMP: How to correctly nest both MASTER and FOR in a PARALLEL block?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, openmp, openmpi

I am working on a program with both OpenMP and OpenMPI.

For the process running on the initial node, I'd like to have one thread working as a scheduler (interact with other nodes) and others doing the computations.

The code structure is like:

```
int computation(...)
{
    #pragma parallel for .....
}

int main(...)
{
    ...
    if (mpi_rank == 0) // initial node
    {
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            #pragma omp master
            {
                // task scheduling for other nodes
            }
            {
                // WRONG: said 4 threads in total, this block will be executed for
                // 3 times simultaneously, and the nested "for" in the function
                // will spawn 4 threads each as well
                // so ACTUALLY 3*4+1=13 threads here!
                int computation(...);
            }
        }
    }
    else // other nodes
    {
        // get a task from node 0 scheduler by MPI
        int computation(...);
    }
}
```

What I want is that, in the initial node, the scheduler takes one thread, and only one computation function is executed at the same time, so only 4 threads are used simultaneously at most.

I also tried:

```
int computation(...)
{
    register int thread_use = omp_get_max_threads();    // this is 4
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        --thread_use;   // if initial node, use 3
    }
    #pragma parallel for ..... num_threads(thread_use)
}

int main(...)
{
    ...
    if (mpi_rank == 0) // initial node
    {
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            #pragma omp master
            {
                // task scheduling for other nodes
            }
            #pragma omp single
            {
                // WRONG: nest "for" can only use 1 thread
                int computation(...);
            }
        }
    }
    else // other nodes
    {
        // get a task from node 0 scheduler by MPI
        int computation(...);
    }
}
```

...or

```
//other parts are the same as above
if (mpi_rank == 0) // initial node
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        #pragma omp master
        {
            // task scheduling for other nodes
        }
        {
            // WRONG: nest "for" can only use 1 thread
            int computation(...);
        }
    }
}
```

...but none of them worked.

How should I arrange the blocks with OpenMP to achieve my goal? Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you want to specify nested parallelism in OpenMP, you need to set the environment variable `OMP_NESTED` to `true`.

Then, a possible implementation could look like the following:

```
// Parallel region. Topmost level
#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
{
    #pragma omp section
    scheduling_function();

    #pragma omp section
    compute_function();
}
```

Where `scheduling_function()` is a single threaded function, and `compute_function()` structure is similar to:

```
void compute_function() {
    // Nested parallel region. Bottommost level
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        computation();
    }
}
```

More information on [OpenMP nested parallelism](https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/using-nested-parallelism-in-openmp)

Comment: Terrific! Thanks very much.

Comment: Take into account that you can also set the number of threads used in each nesting level with comma separated values in `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable.